# How can I hide tkinter widgets based a radiobutton selection?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write Python 3 code using tkinter to generate volume calculations based on entered data.

Currently, my code works, but what I would like to do is have the widgets for sphere disappear when rectangular prism is selected via the radio buttons, and vice versa, so that only the pertinent items are shown.

I've found some ideas but I'm having difficulties implementing them in my current setup. If someone could help, I'd very much appreciate it.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from volumes import * #basic volume calculations 
import sys

def calculate(): #assigns vars, calls volumes module

    x = option.get()
    if x == 1:
        heightx = heighttxt.get()
        widthx = widthtxt.get()
        lengthx = lengthtxt.get()

        height = float(heightx)
        width = float(widthx)
        length = float(lengthx)

        volume= rp_volume(length, width, height)

        messagebox.showinfo('You selected Rectangular Prism', volume) #displays calculation result

    if x == 2:
        radx = radtxt.get()
        radius = float(radx)
        volume = sp_volume(radius)
        messagebox.showinfo('You selected Sphere', volume) #displays calculation result


window = Tk() #creates window ident

window.title("Volume Calculator")
window.geometry('450x300')

option = IntVar()
option.set(1)

Radiobutton(window, text="Rectangular Prism", variable=option, value=1).grid(column=1, row=1)
Radiobutton(window, text="Sphere", variable=option, value=2).grid(column=2, row=1)


heightlbl = Label(window, text="Enter the height: ", padx=5, pady=5) #creates ident labels

widthlbl = Label(window, text="Enter the width: ", padx=5, pady=5)

lengthlbl = Label(window, text="Enter the length: ", padx=5, pady=5)

radlbl = Label(window, text ="Or enter the radius of a sphere: ", padx=5, pady=5)


heighttxt = Entry(window,width=10) #creates entry boxes

widthtxt = Entry(window,width=10)

lengthtxt = Entry(window,width=10)

radtxt = Entry(window, width=10)


calcbtn = Button(window, text="Calculate the volume", command=calculate, padx=5, pady=5) #hey it's a button that calls the calculate function!

quitbtn = Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.destroy) #quit button does what it says on the tin


heightlbl.grid(column=1, row=3) #assigns grid positions (preferred to pack for precise layout)
widthlbl.grid(column=1, row=4)
lengthlbl.grid(column=1, row=5)
radlbl.grid(column=1, row=6)
heighttxt.grid(column=2, row=3)
widthtxt.grid(column=2, row=4)
lengthtxt.grid(column=2, row=5)
radtxt.grid(column=2, row=6)
calcbtn.grid(column=2, row=7)
quitbtn.grid(column=2, row=8)



window.mainloop() #closes window mainloop
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can put the required widgets for the rectangular_prism and the sphere in different frames and add a command parameter to the radio buttons which when selected will show the corresponding the frame and `grid_forget` the other. Here is the code. (Note that, I don't know anything about this *volumes* module, so you change that accordingly)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def calculate(): #assigns vars, calls volumes module
    x = option.get()
    if x == 1:
        heightx = heighttxt.get()
        widthx = widthtxt.get()
        lengthx = lengthtxt.get()

        height = float(heightx)
        width = float(widthx)
        length = float(lengthx)

        volume = length*width*height

        messagebox.showinfo('You selected Rectangular Prism', volume) #displays calculation result

    if x == 2:
        radx = radtxt.get()
        radius = float(radx)
        volume = 4/3*3.14*radius**3
        messagebox.showinfo('You selected Sphere', volume) #displays calculation result

def recprism():
    sphere_frame.grid_forget()
    rec_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

def sphere():
    rec_frame.grid_forget()
    sphere_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

window = Tk() #creates window ident

window.title("Volume Calculator")
window.geometry('450x300')

option = IntVar()

Radiobutton(window, text="Rectangular Prism", variable=option, value=1, command=recprism).grid(column=0, row=0)
Radiobutton(window, text="Sphere", variable=option, value=2, command=sphere).grid(column=1, row=0)

rec_frame = Frame(window)
sphere_frame = Frame(window)

heightlbl = Label(rec_frame, text="Enter the height: ", padx=5, pady=5) #creates ident labels
widthlbl = Label(rec_frame, text="Enter the width: ", padx=5, pady=5)
lengthlbl = Label(rec_frame, text="Enter the length: ", padx=5, pady=5)

radlbl = Label(sphere_frame, text ="Enter the radius of a sphere: ", padx=5, pady=5)

heighttxt = Entry(rec_frame, width=10) #creates entry boxes
widthtxt = Entry(rec_frame, width=10)
lengthtxt = Entry(rec_frame, width=10)

radtxt = Entry(sphere_frame, width=10)

calcbtn = Button(window, text="Calculate the volume", command=calculate, padx=5, pady=5) #hey it's a button that calls the calculate function!
quitbtn = Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.destroy) #quit button does what it says on the tin


heightlbl.grid(column=0, row=0) #assigns grid positions (preferred to pack for precise layout)
widthlbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
lengthlbl.grid(column=0, row=2)
radlbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
heighttxt.grid(column=1, row=0)
widthtxt.grid(column=1, row=1)
lengthtxt.grid(column=1, row=2)
radtxt.grid(column=1, row=0)

calcbtn.grid(column=1, row=1)
quitbtn.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]